# Перепись один блок текста другим

Tags: jquery

В блоке с id="words" выберите текст hello world и добавьте его в блок с id="insert" в <span> вместо строки "abracadabra"
вот нароботки

```
<html>
<div id="words">
    <p>что-то там...</p>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <!--вот это выбираем--->
</div>
<div id="insert">
    <p>text <span>1</span>
    </p>
    <p>text <span>2</span>
    </p>
    <p>text 3 <span>abracadabra<!-- вот сюда вставляем--></span>
    </p>

</html>
<script>
    var y = $('#words').has(':contains("hello world")'); //выбрал hello world
    var z = $('div#insert').children().eq(3).has('span:contains("abracadabra")').append(y)
        //в итоге хрень получается
</script>
```

Comment: А вопрос то в чем? Оформите код на jsfiddle.

Comment: А вопрос то в чем?в том что запрос у меня неправильный и его нужно как-то переписать

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так, вроде работает, но хочу заметить один ньюанс: скрипт ориентируется по индексам, если добавить к примеру тег span вначале, то номер индекса изменится.

```
var s = $('#words p').eq(1).html(); // ищем строку hello world
$("#insert span").eq(2).html(s); // заменяем текст в span
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/8zmrR/)**

```
// Получаем дочерний(-ие) элемент(-ы) из #words, содержащие строку 'hello world'
var results = getElementByContent('#words', '', 'hello world');
// Если найден хотя бы один такой элемент
if (results.length > 0) {
    // Получаем дочерний(-ие) span из #insert, содержащие строку 'abracadabra'
    var target = getElementByContent('#insert', 'span', 'abracadabra');
    // Если найден хотя бы один такой элемент
    if (target.length > 0) {
        // Заменяем все вхождения 'abracadabra' на 'hello world' внутри этих элементов
        target.text(target.text().replace(/abracadabra/g, 'hello world'));
    }    
}
/**
 * @text     - искомая строка 
 * @haystack - селектор тэга-обертки
 * @specific - селектор дочернего тэга, по умолчанию '*', т.е. любой дочерний элемент
 */
function getElementByContent (haystack, specific, text) {
    specific = (!specific || typeof specific !== 'string') ? '*' : specific;
    // Выбрать все дочерние элементы haystack
    // Оставить из них только specific, содержащие text
    return $(haystack).find('*').filter(specific + ':contains("'+text+'")');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Что за `contains` ещё, я бы сделал так:

```
$('.words').each(function(ind){
     var txt = $(this).text();
     if (txt=='hellow world') {
           $('.text').eq(ind).text(txt);
     }
});
```

Сорри пишу с телефона, при условии что кейвордам задан класс `.words` а куда их нужно вписать класс .text